# How to query all the reference ids as from different documents of collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection named "**sectionstudents**" where data are saved in the following style:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605df416e91c9d54184921bb"),
    "course" : ObjectId("5fdcbcace5a1ba11191b0823"),
    "section" : ObjectId("60036d2ae3e2866e606845a8"),
    "student" : ObjectId("6027fdb087d0b94d18611db4"),
    
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603605a3ce8d63116c5ce6fc"),
    "course" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
    "section" : ObjectId("6002fe44cf5e2b51a8d730e1"),
    "student" : ObjectId("6027fdb087d0b94d18611db4"),
    
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("602941880fce660b7ce2a79d"),
    "course" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
    "section" : ObjectId("6002fae3e58bc750b4394229"),
    "student" : ObjectId("6027fdb087d0b94d18611db4"),
    
}
```

I want to return all the course details as an array from the documents for the specific student that matched with the "**student**" objcetId. For example, if the student with an id **6027fdb087d0b94d18611db4** has three courses, I want the courses array as like:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fdcbcace5a1ba11191b0823"),
    "courseCode" : "history 101",
    "title" : "History of Ancient Greek",
    "description" : "It is a long established fact
 },
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
    "courseCode" : "history 101",
    "title" : "History of Ancient Greek",
    "description" : "It is a long established fact that a reader 
 },
 

 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
    "courseCode" : "history 101",
    "title" : "History of Ancient Greek",
    "description" : "It is a long established fact that a reader
  }
]
```

Not just like

```
[
   ObjectId("5fdcbcace5a1ba11191b0823"),
   ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
   ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da")
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter the required student using `$match` stage.
2. Group the result by `student` and accumulate all `course` into `courses` array.
3. Perform join with `courses` collection using `$lookup` operator.

Try this:

```js
db.sectionstudents.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "student" : ObjectId("6027fdb087d0b94d18611db4")
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$student",
            courses: { $push: "$course" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "courses",
            localField: "courses",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "courses"
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6027fdb087d0b94d18611db4"),
    "courses" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fdcbcace5a1ba11191b0823"),
            "courseCode" : "history 101",
            "title" : "History of Ancient Greek",
            "description" : "It is a long established fact"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
            "courseCode" : "history 101",
            "title" : "History of Ancient Greek",
            "description" : "It is a long established fact that a reader"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1db"),
            "courseCode" : "history 101",
            "title" : "History of Ancient Greek",
            "description" : "It is a long established fact that a reader"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What to do if I want to get course details of each course as an array, not just as an array of course ids? Do I need to perform another query or is it possible in the same aggregation ?

Comment: In the same query perform join operation to the collection containing course details using `$lookup` operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match.

Comment: update the question with necessary data from the required collection if you need any help.

Comment: I have updated my question with the required data,. I would be really grateful if you respond.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.